# Formatting of equations

Tags: equations

I have the following equation:

[image]

But my professor want it to be like this (photoshoped):

[image]

He told me, I should use something like "left equation" or so..

I tried the following:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E_{support(\hat{X})}[support(X)] = \\
& \frac{\mathit{support}(\langle \text{Ware A}, 1, 5\rangle)}{\mathit{support}(\langle \text{Ware A}, 1, 10\rangle)} \cdot \frac{\mathit{support}(\langle \text{Ware B}, 2, 4\rangle)}{\mathit{support}(\langle \text{Ware B}, 2, 4\rangle)} \cdot \mathit{support}(\hat{X})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

But it doesn't look like it should. Maybe you can help me?!

Thank you very much for your support!!

Comment: try `multline` instead of `split`, and remove the `&`.  check documentation in the `amsmath` users guide: `texdoc amsmath`.

Comment: Maybe "left equation" means use the "fleqn" in the document class? For the style, I prefer using the environment "align" to split equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Barbara says, you can use `multline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\supp}{support}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\inner}{\langle}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
  E_{\supp(\hat{X})}[\supp(X)]\\
  = \frac{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware A}, 1, 5})}{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware A}, 1, 10)}}
  \cdot \frac{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware B}, 2, 4})}{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware B}, 2, 4})}
  \cdot \supp(\hat{X})
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

You can also use `align` with `\MoveEqLeft`:

```
\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft E_{\supp(\hat{X})}[\supp(X)]\\
  &= \frac{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware A}, 1, 5})}{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware A}, 1, 10)}}
  \cdot \frac{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware B}, 2, 4})}{\supp(\inner{\text{Ware B}, 2, 4})}
  \cdot \supp(\hat{X})
\end{align*}
```

[image: output2]

P.S. Notice the differencce in the placement of the second line relative to the first one; with `multline` it's flushed to the right and with `\MoveEqLeft` it's indented a specific amount.

Comment: Should be the "=" also in the first case in second line? or only by using align? Thx for your help!

Comment: I've now changed it in the first case.

Comment: @mrbela, for displayed formulas the relation should start the line instead of ending it. If it ends the line it is easily overlooked.